# React Navigation app crashes on release mode or via ipa on ios but works fine in debug mode

Tags: ios, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

React native App with [react navigation library](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/3.x/getting-started.html) crashes on ios simulator and devices in release mode or via ipa using Xcode but runs fine on debug mode and also works fine in android.

```
React Native  - 0.56.0
React Navigation - 3.12.1
Used NPM
```

Here is the link to codebase :  https://www.google.com/url?q=https://github.com/vikassahutech/ReactNavigationProject.git&sa=D&source=hangouts&ust=1568994195895000&usg=AFQjCNHChBAkhb6hqpDXGkFsR2sv9GXNmg

Package / configurations used:

```
Package.json :

{
"name": "SampleProject",
"version": "0.0.1",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
"start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
"test": "jest",
"android": "cd ./android && ./gradlew app:assembleDebug && ./gradlew installDebug"
},
"dependencies": {
"@babel/runtime": "^7.5.5",
"react": "^16.9.0",
"react-native": "0.56.0",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "1.0.15",
"react-native-reanimated": "^1.2.0",
"react-navigation": "^3.12.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
"babel-jest": "24.9.0",
"babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
"babel-preset-react-native": "5.0.2",
"jest": "24.9.0",
"react-test-renderer": "16.4.1"
},
"jest": {
"preset": "react-native"
}
}
```

Here are console messages:

```
2019-09-17 18:48:36.339 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.default')

This error is located at:
in r
in t
in RCTView
in RCTView
in n
in n
in t
in t
in RCTView
in e
in n
in n
in r
in r
in t
in n
in n
in RCTView
in e
in a
in RCTView
in RCTView
in t
2019-09-17 18:48:36.344 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] TypeError: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.default')

This error is located at:
in r
in t
in RCTView
in RCTView
in n
in n
in t
in t
in RCTView
in e
in n
in n
in r
in r
in t
in n
in n
in RCTView
in e
in a
in RCTView
in RCTView
in t

This error is located at:
in n
in RCTView
in e
in a
in RCTView
in RCTView
in t
2019-09-17 18:48:36.346 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] TypeError: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.default')

This error is located at:
in r
in t
in RCTView
in RCTView
in n
in n
in t
in t
in RCTView
in e
in n
in n
in r
in r
in t
in n
in n
in RCTView
in e
in a
in RCTView
in RCTView
in t

This error is located at:
in n
in RCTView
in e
in a
in RCTView
in RCTView
in t
2019-09-17 18:48:36.363 [fatal][tid:com.facebook.react.ExceptionsManagerQueue] Unhandled JS Exception: TypeError: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.default')

This error is located at:
in r
in t
in RCTView
in RCTView
in n
in n
in t
in t
in RCTView
in e
in n
in n
in r
in r
in t
in n
in n
in RCTView
in e
in a
in RCTView
in RCTView
in t

This error is located at:
in n
in RCTView
in e
in a
in RCTView
in RCTView
in t
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Getting same error in RN version 57.8, have you got the solution?